# Is there a way to automatically check that `api` and `implementation` dependencies are correct in Gradle build scripts?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

Gradle deprecated the `compile` configuration and replaced it with `api` and `implementation`. I already understand the difference between the two, and I'd like to err on the conservative side of assuming that something is `implementation` unless it can be proven to require `api`. But we have a lot of dependencies and determining this on a case by case basis is too much manual work.

Is there a way to *automatically* detect whether a given dependency has to be `api`?

(Nebula's [gradle-lint-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin) would usually be the ultimate solution to verifying this sort of thing, but it turns out not to support `api` and `implementation` at all, and tells us that our build is broken, and suggests adding `compile` dependencies back.)